# Non-abelian groups of order $27p$ for $p>3$ prime, $3 \nmid p-1$. Verification of conjecture and what is needed to prove it

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, solution-verification, finite-groups, sylow-theory

You may assume that there are $2$ non-abelian groups of order $27$ up to isomorphism:

- The [Heisenberg group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_group) over $\mathbb{Z} / 3 \mathbb{Z}$. Call it $\mathrm{He}_3$.
- The [extra special](https://Extra%20special%20group) group of order $27$, call it $3_{-}^{1+2}$.

I wish to classify the non-abelian groups of order $27p$ for $p>3$ prime, $3 \nmid p-1$. (The smallest such orders are $135$, $297$, $459$, $621$, $783$, $\dots$)

Looking through [GroupNames](https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/%7Ematyd/GroupNames/index500.html), I conjecture that there are only $2$ non-abelian groups of this order, namely $\mathrm{He}_3 \times C_p$ and $3_{-}^{1+2} \times C_p$.

What I'm asking:

- Is this conjecture true?
- What technology do I need to prove it? I know Sylow theory, for example. Would I need anything more sophisticated than that?

Comment: Note the simpler argument that I added.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I have read through both of your answers and they are exactly what I am looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Note: I just finished teaching a lecture on semi-direct products and their constructions, so my  mind went there, especially as I know the structure of the automorphism groups at issue well; but as Steve D points out in comments, you don't even need the automorphism groups and there is a simpler solution that only uses the Sylow theorems, and which I have added below under the horizontal line.)

The only additional thing you need is to know the automorphism groups of the nonabelian groups of order $27$, and of the abelian groups of order $27$.

Let $G$ be a group of order $27p$ with $p$ a prime, $p\gt 3$ and $3\nmid p-1$. The number of $3$-Sylow subgroups of $G$ is congruent to $1$ modulo $3$ and divides $27p$, hence is either $1$ or $p$. But if $3\nmid p-1$, then it cannot be $p$. So the $3$-Sylow subgroup of $G$ is normal. Call it $N$.

Let $C_p$ be a subgroup of order $p$ of $G$ (necessarily cyclic). Then $G$ is a semidirect product of $N$ by $C_p$, since $G=NC_p$ and $N\triangleleft G$. We just need to see what kind of actions $C_p$ can have on $N$.

We have $5$ cases:

1. $N$ is cyclic of order $27$. The automorphism group of $N$ is cyclic, of order $\phi(27) = 18 = 2\times 3^2$, so the action of $C$ on $N$ is trivial, and we have a direct product, which is cyclic of order $27p$.
2. $N$ is isomorphic to $C_9\times C_3$, where $C_n$ is the cyclic group of order $n$. As shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/27208/742), the automorphism group here has order $\phi(9)\phi(3)3^2 = 4\times 3^4$, and again that means that any map $C_9\to\mathrm{Aut}(C_9\times C_3)$ is trivial, so we have a direct product, which is isomorphic to $C_3\times C_{9p}$.
3. $N$ is elementary abelian. Then the automorphism group of $N$ is isomorphic to $\mathsf{GL}(3,3)$, which has order $(3^3-1)(3^3-3)(3^3-9) = (26)(24)(18)$. The prime factors are $2$, $3$, and $13$, so you could have a nontrivial semidirect product $N\rtimes C_{p}$ if $p=13$... but in that case $3\mid 13-1$, which we have excluded. For any other prime $p\gt 3$ the action is trivial, so again we get an abelian group, this time isomorphic to $C_3\times C_3\times C_{3p}$.
4. $N$ is the Heisenberg group of order $27$. As noted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/18496/742), the automorphism group is isomorphic to
   $$\mathsf{AGL}(2,3) = \left\{ \begin{pmatrix}a & b& e\\ c& d& f\\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix} : a,b,c,d,e,f \in \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z},\; ad-bc \neq 0 \right\}.$$
   The order of the group is $9$ times the number of choices for $a,b,c,d$. This is equal to the number of ordered pairs of linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb{F}_3^2$, which is $(9-1)(9-3)=2^4\times 3$; so any homomorphism from $C_p$ to $\mathsf{AGL}(2,3)$ is trivial, hence the action of $C_p$ on $N$ is trivial, and $G\cong N\times C_p$.
5. $N$ is the nonabelian group of order $27$ that has an element of order $9$. Again in Jack Schmidt's post quoted above he notes the automorphism group can be identified with
   $$\left\{ \begin{pmatrix}a & b& 0\\ 0& 1& 0\\ c & d & 1\end{pmatrix} : a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z},\; a ≠ 0 \right\}.$$
   This group has order $2\times 3^3$, so any morphism from $C_p$ to the automorphism group of $N$ is trivial and we get $G\cong N\times C_p$.

So the only groups of order $27p$ with $p$ primes, $p\gt 3$, $3\nmid p-1$ are abelian, or of the form $N\times C_p$ where $C_p$ is cyclic of order $p$ and $N$ is nonabelian of order $27$. If you drop the restriction on $3\nmid p-1$ but require the $3$-Sylow to be normal, then you get another nonabelian group by letting $C_{13}$ act on the elementary abelian group of order $27$.

---

A simpler solution uses only the Sylow theorems, as pointed out by Steve D below. We already know there is a single $3$-Sylow subgroup, so to prove that $G\cong N\times C_p$ it is enough to show there is a single $p$-Sylow subgroup. The number of $p$-Sylow subgroups must divide $27p$ and be congruent to $1$ modulo $p$, so it must divide $27$. The divisors of $27$ greater than $1$ are $3$, $9$, and $27$. The only prime such that $3\equiv 1\pmod{p}$ or $9\equiv 1\pmod{p}$ is $p=2$, which is excluded for being smaller than $3$. The primes for which $27\equiv 1\pmod{p}$ are $2$ and $13$, and $2$ is excluded for being smaller than $3$, and $13$ because $3\mid 13-1$. Thus, there must be a unique Sylow $p$-subgroup as well, so $G\cong N\times C_p$. The abelian $N$ give abelian groups, the nonabelian groups have the desired form.

Comment: Great answer. Another way to approach this is to ask how many Sylow $p$ subgroups there can be (answer: 1). Then you know you have a direct product.

Comment: @SteveD Ehr... yes, of course. And that's easier. Because the number must divide $27$ and be $1$ mod $p$, so $p\gt 27$ forces $1$; $3$ or $9$ subgroups forces $p=2$, and $27$  subgroups forces $p=2$ or $p=13$, and the latter is excluded. I'll add that.